# Cardinality of Cross Product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $|A|=|A'|$ and $|B|=|B'|$. Show that $|A \times B|=|A' \times B'|$.
How would I go about proving this? Would I have to show that $|A \times B|=|A' \times B'|$ is a bijection? Or do I have to do something with cardinal multiplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our goal is to show that $|A \times B| = |A' \times B'|$ by finding a bijection (one to one and onto function) from $A\times B$ to $A'\times B'$.  That is, we want a bijection $h:A\times B \to A' \times B'$.  Once we've found this bijection, we'll know (by the definition of cardinality) that these (product) sets have to be the same size.

Now, we know that $|A| = |A'|$, so there must be some bijection $f:A\to A'$.  Similarly, we know that $|B| = |B'|$, so there must be some bijection $g:B \to B'$.  I will define the bijection $h$ as follows:

For any $(a,b) \in A \times B$ (that is, a pair $(a,b)$ where $a$ is a member of $A$ and $b$ is a member of $B$), $h(a,b) = (f(a),g(b))$.

This is a function from $A \times B$ to $A' \times B'$. In order to complete the proof, you'll have to show that the function $h$ is a bijection.  That is, prove the following: if $f:A\to A'$ is one to one and onto and $g:B\to B'$ is one to one and onto, then $h:A\times B \to A'\times B'$ given by $h(a,b) = (f(a),g(b))$ is *also* one to one and onto.

Answer (score 3):

Just find a bijection from $A\times B$ to $A'\times B\,'$. Use the ones from $A$ to $A'$ and $B$ to $B\,'$ whose existence is guaranteed by the hypothesis.

Comment: So would I define a map h: A×B --> A'×B' by h(x,y)={<x,y>:x∈X×Y} ?

Comment: @Nayru: That doesn’t really make sense: you’ve not said what $X$ and $Y$ are, you’ve used $x$ to mean at least two different things, and $\{\langle x,y\rangle:x\in X\times Y\}$ is not an element of $A'\times B\,'$.

Comment: So could I define it as h={<x,y>:x∈A and y∈B}?

Comment: @Nayru: No: $\{\langle x,y\rangle:x\in A\text{ and }y\in B\}$ is just $A\times B$. For each $\langle x,y\rangle\in A\times B$ you need $h(\langle x,y\rangle)$ to be an element of $A'\times B\,'$: it should be something of the form $\langle x',y'\rangle$, where $x'\in A'$ and $y'\in B\,'$. Your problem is to figure out how to choose $x'$ and $y'$ so that $h$ is actually a bijection; that’s where the second sentence of my answer comes in.